# Find out particular id

Tags: sql

I have a table in sql like this:

```
id               billpay
-------------------------
1024             0
1024             0
1024             1
1025             1
1025             1
```

I want to retrieve only those id having billpay 1

Please help me with this

Comment: I think you should modify your requirement to something like: I want to retrieve only those ids having billpay = 1 and *nothing but billpay = 1*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN COALESCE(billpay, 0) <> 1 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

The above will select only those `id`s associated to `billpay=1` and nothing but `billpay=1`.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c44fc/4)

Comment: @surajkumarghosi Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @surajkumar  just click on the tick button present on the left of each answer. You can only accept one answer.

Comment: when i click on button it show me you need require 15 reputation

Comment: @surajkumar this is the up vote button. Right below is the down vote button.  The accept button is the **tick** below the down vote button.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:
`SELECT id FROM tabel WHERE billpay = 1;`

Comment: it give me both id but i want only retive those id having only  billpay 1

in this question 1024 id haveing three value 0 0 1 and 2015 having two value 1 1 in.
i want to retrive only 1025

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select distinct id from yourtable where billpay = 1
```

Comment: it give me both id but i want only retive those id having only billpay 1 in this question 1024 id haveing three value 0 0 1 and 2015 having two value 1 1 in. i want to retrive only 1025

Answer (score 1):

```
select ID
from MyData
Where billpay = 1

Group By ID
```

The group by will list unique IDs

```
select ID
from MyData A
Where not exists (select 'X' from MyData B where B.billpay <> 1 and  B.ID = A.ID)
Group By ID
```

This will only list IDs where billpay is only 1

Comment: i want only id having all  billy pay  should be 1 if any one is 0 then its not retrieve .. so my answer should be 1025 beacuse its having billypay 1

please help me

Comment: Why group by when no aggregate functions?

Comment: Means entry 1025 will only be listed once. Could have used select distinct instead, but I prefer to use group by

Answer (score 1):

This will retrieve those ids in ascending order which have at least one record in the table with `billpay = 1`.
The `DISTINCT` keyword will ensure you don't receive back multiple records with the same `id`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
  FROM [TableName]
 WHERE billpay = 1
 ORDER BY id ASC
```

If you want to exclude those ids which also have records with billpay = 0, then use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
  FROM [TableName]
 WHERE billpay = 1
   AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM [TableName] WHERE billpay = 0)
 ORDER BY id ASC
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The following query selects the ids from group of ids where the number of records with billpay = 1 is the same as the number of records in the group

```
select id 
from bills 
group by id
having sum(billpay) = count(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to find rows with no other than billplay 1, use `DISTINCT` to return only one of each id found.

```
select distinct id
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t1.id = t2.id
                    and t2.billpay <> 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `GROUP BY` +`MIN` statement to exclude Id's with existing `billpay=0`

```
SELECT id 
FROM yourtable 
GROUP BY id
HAVING MIN(billpay)=1
```